# jQuery hiding single class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm slightly new to javascript and jquery and have an issue/question. I'm not sure if it can be done but I have faith that it can be. The thing is, I'm not sure how to best explain it so I'm having trouble finding the answer. First off, here is my code...

```
HTML

<div class="media">
  <div class="file">
    <button class="close"></button>
    <img src="img/video-image.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="file">
    <button class="close"></button>
    <img src="img/record-image.png" />
  </div>
</div>

Javascript

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function () {
    $(".file").hide();
  });
});
```

Obviously, I want to click the button to make the image disappear and from what you can see, it will hide all divs with the file class. That's not what I want. I want to just close the div that contains the button you have clicked. I know that I can used ids but I would rather not. I have a lot more of the similar situations for what I'm working on and I am just looking for compact code. Hopefully this makes sense.

Much obliged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function () {
       $(this).parent(".file").hide();  
    });
 });
```